# How to use Amazon Elasticsearch to index dynamodb data?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, logstash, amazon-dynamodb, kibana

I want to create a search engine, using javascript for the cllient side and Amazon ES for the backend. However, since i am just discovering the elasticsearch api, i am looking for a detailed explanation of how i can index my dynamodb entries in real-time and then building a customized search engine with some features like auto suggest, auto filling etc.

I can't find any tutorial on the web that explain the entire process.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin can help with streaming the data from DynamoDB:
https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb

The readme has some information, I'm not sure if that's the kind of detail you are after, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: I have a problem. I am following the instruction but when it comes the time to install the logstash gem and typing `jruby -S gem install --local logstash-input-dynamodb-1.0.0-java.gem` in the cmd prompt i got an error that means it cannot find a valid logstash gem in any repository. Also when i want to insale the plugin with `bin/plugin install --no-verify logstash-input-dynamodb` i have an error saying that bin is not recognized as a command. I don't know what to do i successfully installed Jruby and apache maven and i want to use logstash input with Amazon ES not in localhosted.